# Async Waterfall of proprietary event trigger functions in MS Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I encountered the following problem while setting up dependent option sets.
The usual approach is to fire a .clearOptions() on the option set to remove all options. These days, this triggers the .fireOnChange() to fire as well. And that in my case triggers the .fireOnChange() of the dependent option set also, and since there is no option left it will always be null.

My question now is. Is it possible to get 3rd party, not-in-code-changeable async event calls in line so that they are fired when they are done and then move to the next async call?